# XML Provider does not recognize tags

Tags: xml, f#, f#-data

I am using [XML provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html) for processing xml files or I am trying to use it.
Look at the following code:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Xml.Linq
open FSharp.Data
open System.Net

type InputXml = XmlProvider<"C:\Temp\sample.xml">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let input = InputXml.Load("C:\Temp\sample.xml")

    for customer in input.GetCustomers() do
        for order in customer.GetOrders() do
            for line in order.GetOrderLines() do
                printfn "Customer: %s, Order: %s, Item: %s, Quantity: %d" customer.Name order.Number line.Item line.Quantity

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I've got compiler error

```
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
The field, constructor or member 'GetCustomers' is not defined  D:\f#\samples\Program.fs    16  27  samples
```

And the xml file structure looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Customers>
  <Customer name="ACME">
    <Order Number="A012345">
      <OrderLine Item="widget" Quantity="1"/>
    </Order>
    <Order Number="A012346">
      <OrderLine Item="trinket" Quantity="2"/>
    </Order>
  </Customer>
  <Customer name="Southwind">
    <Order Number="A012347">
      <OrderLine Item="skyhook" Quantity="3"/>
      <OrderLine Item="gizmo" Quantity="4"/>
    </Order>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your string literals have unescaped backslashes.

Comment: @ildjarn F# interactive tells me that because the characters following the backslashes do not form actual escape sequences, the string does specify the file name accurately.  If you change the first letter of `"Temp"` to a `'t'` then the file name becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the package do you use?

If I reference the current one `2.1.1` from NuGet, `XmlProvider` works like a charm and presents the nodes as properties.

```
open System
open FSharp.Data

type InputXml = XmlProvider<"C:\Temp\sample.xml">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let input = InputXml.Load("C:\Temp\sample.xml")

    for customer in input.Customers do
        for order in customer.Orders do
            for line in order.OrderLines do
                printfn "Customer: %s, Order: %s, Item: %s, Quantity: %d" customer.Name order.Number line.Item line.Quantity

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```